# Modify JSON from Mysql & PHP to compatible with Rickshaw Graph

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to show last data from MySQL using [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) via PHP

It's required to look like this :

```
[
    {
        "data": [ { "x": 1350995278, "y": 26.12 }, 
                  { "x": 1350995276, "y": 26.19 }, 
                  { "x": 1350995273, "y": 26.12 }, 
                  { "x": 1350995271, "y": 26.19 }, 
                  { "x": 1350995268, "y": 26.19 } ]
    }
]
```

but my PHP with `json_encode` function returns it a bit differently.  How should i fix it ?

PHP CODE:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
        $r[] = $row;
        $items[] = array('x' => $row['unixtime'], 'y' => $row['sensor']);
    }
    print json_encode($items);
```

PHP OUTPUT:

```
[{"x":"1350996886","y":"26.06"},
 {"x":"1350996884","y":"26.06"},
 {"x":"1350996881","y":"26.06"},
 {"x":"1350996879","y":"26.06"},
 {"x":"1350996876","y":"26.06"},
 {"x":"1350996874","y":"26.06"},
 {"x":"1350996871","y":"26.06"},
 {"x":"1350996869","y":"26.06"},
 {"x":"1350996866","y":"26.06"},
 {"x":"1350996864","y":"26.06"}]
```

I don't need `""` after `x`: and `Y`: I am new to `PHP` and don't know how to figure out, please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the values to numbers if you don't want them to be quoted:

```
$items[] = array('x' => (float) $row['unixtime'], 'y' => (float) $row['sensor']);
```